# Ember view - fire didInsertElement on BaseView and ExtendedView as well

Tags: ember.js

I have got BaseView and ExtendedView as follows:

```
App.BaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
         alert("BaseView didInsertElement fired");
     }
 });

 App.ExtendedView = App.BaseView.extend({
     didInsertElement: function(){
         alert("ExtendedView didInsertElement fired");
     }
 });
```

I would like didInsertElement event to be fired on both views. Is it possible somehow?

EDIT: But only ExtendedView should be rendered. BaseView should only act like base class.

I will appreciate any response.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would didInsertElement from BaseView to be fired when using ExtendedView you have to write

```
App.ExtendedView = App.BaseView.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this._super();
        alert("ExtendedView didInsertElement fired");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is interesting. I've done something similar: 
`App.BaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElementBase: function(){
         alert("BaseView didInsertElement fired");
     }
 });

 App.ExtendedView = App.BaseView.extend({
     didInsertElement: function(){
         this.didInsertElementBase(arguments);
         alert("ExtendedView didInsertElement fired");
     }
 });`

but your way is much nicer. Thank you. +1

Comment: From other source I've got solution to pass also event arguments:
`this._super.apply(this, arguments);`